# Two proximity sensors in android phone

Tags: android, proximitysensor, proximityapi

In my android phone with two proximity sensors and I can easily log the front proximity sensor value.

```
   if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY){
           Log.d("PROXIMITY",""+event.values[0]); }
```

However, I have no idea to get rear proximity sensor value. I have already search on developer.android.com without any success. I hope someone should have experience to grep value of rear proximity sensor.

Comment: What rear proximity sensor? Which device are you using? My guess that this is a manufacturer customization with no API.

Comment: This is to get distance of object for fast auto focus. Is there any way to get the value?

Comment: If its camera related then it would be in the Camera APIs and I wasn't able to find anything in the existing Camera2 APIs which would expose such a thing. If you are trying to do distance to object then that is a Tango type problem (along with extra hardware sensors): https://get.google.com/tango/